# Comparing varchar2 in Oracle with different charsets?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a column in a table that is defined as `Varchar2(4000)` called `tbl_varchar`.
I get a input argument from the client to a stored procedure that is `varchar2(4000)` as well. I call that `input_varchar`.

I want to update only if the contents has changed:

```
Update table t SET tbl_varchar = input_varchar, updated = sysdate 
WHERE key = input_key and tbl_varchar != input_varchar;
```

I am running this with the same input several times and see that my timestamp is updated everytime but the varchar data doesn't seem to be change.

Can this have anything to do with different char sets on the client and database? If so, what is the best way to confirm it? I don't have any control of the client.

Comment: Both `varchar2` columns must, by definition, be the same character set.  It is possible (well, almost certain) that there is character set conversion happening from Java where strings are UTF-16 encoded to Oracle where a `varchar2` can't be UTF-16 encoded.  But that should be consistent from the same application.  It's very unlikely that you're running the same application on the same machine multiple times and getting a different result.

Answer (score 0):

If that's about charset you can try:

```
Update table t SET tbl_varchar = input_varchar, updated = sysdate 
WHERE key = input_key and convert(tbl_varchar, 'US7ASCII') != convert(input_varchar, 'US7ASCII');
```

Or put your charset instead of `'US7ASCII'`

I'd also add `trim()` both values. Maybe issue is with some whitespaces.